# Chrome Node DevTools Inspector stopped listing files

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Title says it all. I haven't made any major code changes and the debugger is still connecting. However, it isn't listing any files:

Did something change in the Node dev tools to stop these files from showing up? This is all very mysterious and I've seen instances of other developers 'losing' their source folder listings when using `--inspect` with Chrome Node DevTools. [image]

However, Cmd/Ctrl-P still lists the files and clicking on file names in the logs still takes me to the files (assuming I don't get some mysterious alternate empty version). Why can I no longer navigate my project's file system from Node Debugger on Chrome?

I have checked to make sure that the files are loaded (they are, as you can see, properly running and these particular microservices are responding as expected and pass tests). So I don't think it's an issue with my code.

Comment: You've switched to "Content scripts" sub-panel. Click `»` to the right of it to select subpanels.

Comment: @wOxxOm Which panel should it be in? I don't have file listings under any of the panels... They are all empty.

Comment: @wOxxOm see here: https://imgur.com/a/4XdsA5i

Comment: @wOxxOm Network and File system are no longer populated... do I need to do something to make them show up?

Comment: @wOxxOm Please scroll down on previous imgur link to see other sub-panel states. As you can see, they are all empty...

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a bug then. If you can find a reliable repro sequence from a new user profile (or after resetting devtools in its settings dialog), post it on https://crbug.com.